# Frobenius dihedral groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How can we show by a direct group-theoretic proof that the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is a Frobenius group iff $n$ is an odd number?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** My assertion is that $D_{2n}$ acts on the vertices of respective $n$-gon. Non-trivial rotations have no fixed points. Further: 1) If $n$ is odd then each reflection has precisely one fixed point. So, $D_{2n}$ is [Frobenius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_group). 2) If $n$ is even then every reflection has precisely two fixed points. So, $D_{2n}$ is not Frobenius.

Comment: For the $n$ even case, this shows only that $D_{2n}$ is not Frobenius in its action as the symmetry group of an $n$-gon. For a complete answer you would need to show that it has no (faithful) action as a Frobenius group.